# Protractor: Import more than one page objects in spec file

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor, pageobjects

I have written below spec code and I have imported 3 page objects in it using require keyword. On running it gives error on second require statement. Please let me know what is the correct way in protractor to import more than one page objects.

```
describe("To test the login functionality", function(){
    var landingPage = require('../page/LandingPage.js');
    var employees = require('../page/EmployeesPage.js');
    var employeeDetails = require('../page/EmployeeDetailPage.js');     

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.get("<website-address>");       
    });

    it("should be able to login",function(){
        landingPage.enterUserName('');
        landingPage.enterPassword('');
        landingPage.clickLoginButton();
        employees.doubleClickFirstEmployee();
        employeeDetails.clickBackButton();
        browser.pause();
    });
});
```

I am receiving below error:

```
  Message:
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
  Stack:
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Comment: Can you tell us on which line is the error occuring? Or can you completely post the error message that you get? The way you `require` modules is proper. Thanks

Comment: Error is occuring on line "var employeeDetails = require('../page/EmployeeDetailPage.js'); "

Comment: Are you sure that `EmployeeDetailPage.js` file has no errors? Also you can try adding variables outside `describe` block if necessary. Thanks

Comment: It has no errors and I tried writing variables outside block but it did not help.

Comment: I just figured out an error on EmployeeDetailPage.js. Resolved it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to an error on in "EmployeeDetailPage.js", the error was being shown on below line:
var employeeDetails = require('../page/EmployeeDetailPage.js');

Resolved the issue by removing error.